# How can I stop perticular ip address to access my web application

Tags: security, playframework, playframework-2.0, ip-address, playframework-2.2

I am making small website in play framework2.2.0, I want to stop unwanted people which perform invalid action and stop my website , few days ago i read that we can set ip address in application.conf which can not access our website. 
or
I want to stop my website for a perticuler user by ip address in play framework 2.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play has NOT any built-in solution for access control, the easiest thing you can do is just placing Play application behind some HTTP server in role of proxy and gate-keeper, which will filter it for you, ie. [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpAccessModule) or [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html).

On the other hand you can also [intercept each request within Global object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaInterceptors) of Play which gives you even better flexibility, although you need to implement it yourself.

Edit: Here you have simple sample for matching IP with some pattern: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/CheckifIPaddressmatchpattern.htm